# SSH into Hadoop cluster using Paramiko, and then executing dependent commands

Tags: ssh, paramiko

I am implementing a python script, which uses paramiko to connect to a hadoop cluster. My problem is that I can SSH to a root user only, and from inside I have to switch user to hdfs to execute my command.
now I need something to automate this switching to HDFS user and then cding into /tmp/ and then executing command from there. I have tried invoke_shell() , it hangs, and also the && inside the exec_command, it also doesnt work.

I am getting a permission denied exception:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: file.txt (Permission denied)
```

There are two workflows that I have thought of:
1st one:

```
 1. sudo -u hdfs -s
 2. cd /tmp/
 3. <execute the command> <outputDir>
```

2nd one:

```
sudo -u hdfs <execution command> /tmp/<outputDir>
```

The first one doesnt give the above error. But the second one throws this. I was trying second one just to avoid the dependent command issue.

Any help or suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Removed Hadoop tags because this is standard Unix user management. You should add your SSH key to the authorized_keys of the hdfs user so that you **can** SSH to it

Comment: I am able to ssh, these commands I want to execute after I am inside, I mean, after the connection is established.

Comment: I understood that part. That's what paramiko (or Ansible) do... What exact issues are you having with that? Like I said, you should ssh as the user you need to be rather than make one of the commands `sudo su `. You also shouldn't need to cd into the tmp folder to run any commands. Regarding the "hanging", you'll need to show your code or the command your trying to run

Comment: Apparently why it was happening was, I was running the script which created the file with the name say xyz.txt with UserA first, and then I was trying to write into that file with UserB. So it was just a permission conflict. Thanks for your time.